# Saving one commit onto another branch without merging the branches

Tags: git

I know about git cherry-pick, but it seems to actually rebase the commit onto the other branch which introduces merge conflicts. Is there any way to just paste a commit onto the history of another branch with no further modifications to the commit or the branch head? For context, I wanted to save a working version and a completed version (which is already on the target branch) of my project onto the same branch, but both have different file contents and the working version has extra files that get deleted with git cherry-pick.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, which is by-design as git is a [Merkle structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree); future commits depend on past commits

You can create a complete diff with `git diff branch1..branch2` to generate a single patch, and then use `git apply` to apply it (effectively this generates one commit that makes branch1 into branch2 directly)

```sh
# git pull -a  # fetch upstream (maybe undesirable)
git diff branch_other..branch_src > ../output.patch

# inspect output

git apply ../output.patch
```